# Excel returns #DIV/0! for simple AVERAGE calculation

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hi Excel is unable to do a simple AVERAGE calculation with values that come from a text truncation.

- C19 is calculated as =LEFT(C18,1)
- C24 is calculated as =LEFT(C23,1)
- C29 is calculated as =LEFT(C28,1)
- Quality Avg (C30) is calculated as

=IF(NOT(AND(ISBLANK(C19),ISBLANK(C24),ISBLANK(C29))),AVERAGE(C19,C24,C29),"")

The error checking shows that each value in the AND function is the correct number. But Excel is unable to calculate the average and returns a #DIV/0!. How can a division by 3 return that error? This is in Excel 2013.

Also, why do the blank columns return #DIV/0!? The IF statement checks for blanks.

[image: #DIV/0! Error]

Comment: The left function returns text....

Comment: "why do the blank columns return #DIV/0!? The IF statement checks for blanks." Do those blank columns still have the LEFT function formulas in place? If so then those formulas may return what looks like a blank but ISBLANK will return FALSE. You might want to use IFERROR function in conjunction with teylyn's suggestion, e.g. `=IFERROR(AVERAGE(C19,C24,C29),"")`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

change the cells with the LEFT function to convert the text to numbers.

```
=LEFT(C18,1)+0
```

or

```
=LEFT(C18,1)*1
```

Now the results are numeric and you can work with them as numbers.

Comment: Thank you. This was the solution with the error check suggested by barry houdini.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:
`=IF(NOT(AND(ISBLANK(C19),ISBLANK(C24),ISBLANK(C29))),AVERAGE(VALUE(C19),VALUE(C24),VALUE(C29)),"")`